# Pandas vectorising application of function objects across whole DataFrame

Tags: pandas, performance

I have a base DataFrame and I want to apply a specific function to each element given by another DataFrame with the same index and columns, for example something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
df_format = pd.DataFrame([[lambda x: f'{x:.1f}', lambda x: f'{x:.2f}'], 
                          [lambda x: f'{x:.3f}', lambda x: f'{x:.4f}']])

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        df.iloc[i,j] = df_format.iloc[i,j](df.iloc[i,j])
        
print(df)
       0       1
0    1.0    2.00
1  3.000  4.0000
```

This isn't vectorised and I wonder if there is a much more efficient way to do this especially for larger DataFrames

Comment: What do the lambdas look like on larger dataframes? Are they mandatory different for each cell? Do the lambda bodies always look like `f'{x:._f}'` with `_` a given integer? What is the shape of the "larger DataFrames"?

Comment: the functions are minimalist examples. Assume that they can be completely generic. assume a larger DataFrame can be upto say 25% of RAM.

Comment: shorter but not sure about efficiency: `def fun(x): return x.iloc[0](x.iloc[1])` and then `pd.concat((df_format,df)).groupby(level=0).agg(fun)`

Answer (score 2):

You could make the code much faster by **working on columns** and using the **`vectorize`** function of **Numpy**. Indeed, direct accesses to Pandas dataframe (using `iloc`) or internal Numpy arrays (using `arr[i]`) are slow. Python loops are very slow too. Moreover, data are stored by column internally making column-wise operations faster than row-wise ones.
Here is a solution to vectorize your operation:

```py
def callOn(func, value):
    return func(value)
for j in range(2):
    # np.vectorize(callOn) generate a function calling callOn(x,y) for 
    # each input pair (x,y) of zip(df_format[j],df[j]).
    df[j] = np.vectorize(callOn)(df_format[j],df[j])
```

However, note that Numpy do not truely vectorize the calls internally since it deals with Python objects/functions. But this problem inherently comes from the assumption that all lambda could be different and are defined as plain Python objects.

On my machine this code is about **200 times faster** than the initial one using the following setup:

```py
nRows, nCols = 1000, 20
fList = [lambda x: f'{x:.1f}', lambda x: f'{x:.2f}', lambda x: f'{x:.3f}', lambda x: f'{x:.4f}']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint([[10 for j in range(nCols)] for i in range(nRows)]))
df_format = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(fList, size=(nRows, nCols)))
```

Comment: hi thanks, this looks good, will try it out